# Removed libgcrypto and some other essential packages, how do I reinstall them?

Tags: re-installation

While removing libgcrypto package, I apparently removed a lot of critical dependencies with it.

Now I don't have access to the GUI, just to a tty.

My problem is how to get those packages missing.

I can't seem to access to internet and don't have a cd to boot from. 
I have a external HD with ubuntu iso which I can mount.

I was wondering if it is possible to get those packages that are missing after mounting it. Or if there is a more ingenious option.

Thanks

Comment: I ended up downloading the packages in another laptop, getting them on an USB and reinstalling them. But if anyone knows the solution for what I have asked, I'm still curious about it.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to get connected to the net using wire cable then please open a pseudo-tty by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> made login with your user and password if requested by the system, then type

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

give your user password when requested, you will not get any screen chars on screen when you type your password so type it, then press enter.

Comment: I can't access the internet on that laptop. That's the reason why I'm asking it is possible to take the files from the mounted iso.